# In the R package textstem, why does stem_word("way") return "wai"

Tags: r, nlp, tidytext

I think the title shares it all. I have used stem_word on a large body of text, and am not understanding this particular result.

In the R package textstem, why does stem_word("way") return "wai"

I understand that this stems words (e.g. "driving" and "drives" become "drive"), but "wai" does not seem to be the stem of "way"

```
library(textstem)
stem_word("way")
```

Answer (score 2):

That's just how stemming works. Stemming tries to find the "significant" root of a word. This particular rule makes it possible to combine "story" and "stories" for example.

```
stem_words(c("story", "stories"))
# [1] "stori" "stori"
```

And in this case, both `way` and `ways` will stem to the same root as well

```
stem_words(c("way","ways"))
# [1] "wai" "wai"
```

Most stemming algorithms don't guarantee to make an actual word, they just try combine words that likely have a common root. And since "y" at the end of a word is often change to "i" when the work is "elongated" by some suffix, you have a better change of grouping related works if you just change all terminal "y"s to "i"s. If that's a problem in your case, you'll have to see if you can choose a different stemming algorithm or write your own to satisfy your particular needs.